# Narrowing member type based on another member

Tags: typescript

```
type Event<S extends string> = {
    name: S
}

const EventHandler = <S extends string, T extends Event<S>[]>(arr: [...T]) => {
    let lastEvent: T[number] = arr[0]
    return {
        set: (event: T[number]) => lastEvent = event,
        emit: (event: typeof lastEvent['name']) => { },
        lastEvent
    }
}

const emitter = EventHandler([{ name: 'A' }, { name: 'B' }])

if(emitter.lastEvent.name === 'A') {
    // `emitter.lastEvent` is now inferred to `{ name: A }`
    
    emitter.emit('B') // compiles, but I want it to only allow the string `A`
}
```

In this contrived example, I create some object `EventHandler` that has some configuration `lastEvent`. Now, I want the parameter of `emit` to be narrowed down depending on the configuration.

However, even though the type of `lastEvent` gets narrowed down in the conditional, I'm unable to narrow down the input of `emit` as a result of that.

Is this possible? Preferably without using user defined type guards...

[EDIT]:

I thought I could make a compromise and add the event object as input to `emit`:

```
emit: (event: T[number], name: typeof event['name']) => { }
```

and then do:

```
emitter.emit({ name: 'A' }, 'B') // why does this compile ?!
```

but that also doesn't get inferred! This seems strange - why can't typescript handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, we would ideally build a discriminated union so that the type of the `emit` function can be narrowed by checking the type of `lastEvent`. This would require us to check the *nested* value of `emitter.lastEvent.name`. But that's a problem since TypeScript currently does not allow narrowing discrimanted unions based on deeply nested properties (see [#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758)).

What we can do for now is to avoid the *nesting* and have the string value of `name` on the top-level of the object.

We can use the union of `T[number]` with a mapped type to build a discriminated union where each union constituent `K` is the discriminant.

```
const EventHandler = <T extends string[]>(arr: [...T]) => {
    let lastEvent: T[number] = arr[0]
    return {
        set: (event: T[number]) => lastEvent = event,
        emit: (event: typeof lastEvent) => { },
        lastEvent
    } as {
        set: (event: T[number]) => void 
    } & {
        [K in T[number]]: {
            emit: (event: K) => void
            lastEvent: K
        }
    }[T[number]]
}
```

This lets us properly narrow the type of `emit` by checking the value of `lastEvent`.

```
const emitter = EventHandler(['A', 'B'])

if(emitter.lastEvent === 'A') {    
    emitter.emit('A')
    

    emitter.emit('B') // Error: Argument of type '"B"' is not assignable 
                      // to parameter of type '"A"'
}

if(emitter.lastEvent === 'B') {
    emitter.emit('A') // Error: Argument of type '"A"' is not assignable 
                      // to parameter of type '"B"'
    
    emitter.emit('B')
}

emitter.set('A')
emitter.set('B')
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsA+gHgMpQgD2EgEwGcojgAnAS0QHMA+KAXigG8BYAKCm6kQEMAthABcUDJwC+nTgGMA9ojKwEyABJ9EBADYRyTKGgAq2PIRJkqtANoBdOgAo+5cqKsA6D4ZsBKJg3ZcPDrAUFp8ZPBIwKKGVogArgIARro2+k7kVgAMNpw8UOQQwPHkiKx5+TxERaL2ECrRULEJyam+jAxhEQ369VEANBWV2AKUjXUNoqCQcgBmoeHAkcjt-lASg4HDXUsNQ+tQ4eVbldXjfcgxcYkp5D5+UHBylARQ+xJQAGTHw9xWANJQahNa6tO42UQBX6VCCjc6TKD-VaPZ4EfbQnbLRr-dE8KQnCRWZo3VK5Dj42QKJSwsb4PTMLHqTQ6cj2KwAcgAguz+lB2QAhdk+aQcSizOpwuluTE9Rhyvnc3wsfL7GnAKVq+xc9neVWS3RuTUCnVQAD0ptgzjkLignPINESUSgcyg02g7IARPyPeygSREHIQuEiJQaPwkjpXXIoGAnIIirpnfM3XyPZyfZIRWKJbSDTKnXLmMalXrc+RDXCtYqzRaYFabXaHUJkEnXeB3WmfX7eIHDkQQ2G+BHoMBo7HyPG6a2U57vezS+qDUbBbrySK1VKzlWdZwNwat8WgA)

Comment: Thanks! The discriminated union hack is really clever ... nice! I really wish typescript supported narrowing on nested properties, since in my real code I need an object there ... I'll see if I can work around it somehow.

Comment: Ok so I really need the nesting. I have a situation where the `Event` type has two fields, like say `{ A: string, B: string }`, and I need to infer the input to `send` to be `Event.B` when checking that `lastEvent` is `Event.A`. Is this not possible?